# Weird behavior of Entity Framework's ObjectContext (v4.0)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm coming from an NHibernate background to Entity Framework v4.0. When I load entities into the ObjectContext, I expect them to be cached there as long as the ObjectContext lives ('1st level cache'). So, if the same query is executed the second time, the objects are already in the ObjectContext and should not be loaded again.

Have a look at this query:

```
        using (var context = new Model1Container()) {
            //load entities from DB
            var entities = context.Entity1Set.ToArray();
            //entities should now be cached in the context (1st level cache)

            //why does this call not use the cached items?
            entities = context.Entity1Set.ToArray();
        }
```

In SQL Server Profiler, I can clearly see that both ToArray() calls trigger a database  query. Why does the second query need a DB roundtrip, as opposed to the NHibernate behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF 4.0 do not support any form of cache, neither first nor second level cache as NHibernate do.

One feature that resembles to NHibernate first-level cache was implemented in EF 4.1.

[EF 4.1 Local Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx)

HTH

Riana

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I've never used NHibernate, but I have been using Entity Framework for the last year or so.

In some ways, the behavior you described makes sense to me. What if the data in the database changes between calls? For example, Entity Framework would have to requery the database to check if any new rows have been added to the database table.

However, executing a LINQ query on the results would not require another roundtrip to the database because Entity Framework would be fetching the existing entities out of the ObjectContext.

```
 var newEntities = entities.Where(x=>x.id==1).ToList();
 var newEntities2 = entities.Where(x=>x.id==1).ToList();
```

Comment: Agreed, based on my experience operations that have to do with a particular ID that is already in the context will not require another round trip to the database.  General operations such as give me all items will always go to the db.

Comment: well this is no surprise, since if you execute the .Where() method on the 'entities' array, you're actually using LINQ to Objects and not LINQ to Entities anymore.

I wonder if LINQ to Entities is generally able to cache results of queries

Comment: another thing: if our ObjectContext lives so long that the data in the database could change between the calls, we can use ObjectContext.Refresh. Most of the time the ObjectContext is very short-lived, so we don't care about changes in the database during its lifetime